# Qual é a finalidade do git update-index?

Tags: git

Eu estava enfrentando problemas com pastas, que deveriam ser ignoradas no repositório, mas não eram mesmo quando colocava no `.gitignore`, e fiz várias pesquisas a fim de solucionar o problema.

Dentre várias pesquisas, vi alguém aconselhando que, em alguns casos, é melhor usar `git update-index --assume-unchanged` do que usar o `.gitignore`.

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade desse comando. Para que ele serve?

E, observando que ele usa o argumento `--assume-unchanged`, existem outros argumentos que possam ser usado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando `update-index` atualiza o índice do GIT, o principal uso é para considerar arquivos modificados como não modificados com o parâmetro `--assume-unchanged`. Outro parâmetro importante é o `--no-assume-unchanged`, que desfaz o comando anterior.

Outro comando importante nesse contexto é:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'
```

Usado para listar arquivos marcados como *assume unchanged*. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363495/2932525).

---

Retirado do manual, os outros parâmetros:

```
git update-index
    [--add] [--remove | --force-remove] [--replace]
    [--refresh] [-q] [--unmerged] [--ignore-missing]
    [(--cacheinfo <mode> <object> <file>)...]
    [--chmod=(+|-)x]
    [--[no-]assume-unchanged]
    [--[no-]skip-worktree]
    [--ignore-submodules]
    [--really-refresh] [--unresolve] [--again | -g]
    [--info-only] [--index-info]
    [-z] [--stdin] [--index-version <n>]
    [--verbose]
    [--] [<file>...]
```

A descrição de cada um dos parâmetros pode ser consultada em https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index